# UWP app-installer auto update not working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am trying auto update my UWP application from remote source. For this I followed these two blogs [handling-auto-updates-for-sideloaded-uwp-and-desktop-bridge-apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/03/22/handling-auto-updates-for-sideloaded-uwp-and-desktop-bridge-apps/)  & [create-appinstallerfile-vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-appinstallerfile-vs) of MSDN. I got this working in Version 1803 (OS Build 17677.1000).

But, I'm able to get auto update work on every other version (For example, if my first version is 0 and it is the version I install first then I get automatic update working for version 1 but not for version 2. And if I update version 2 manually then again I get auto update for version 3).

I've set to check for update on every time the app runs in my .appinstaller file.

Has anyone faced this problem? Can anyone please show me a way to solve this issue?

Comment: You're working on inside preview version. Have you tried it on edition 17134.1?

Comment: I've not tried on edition 17134.1 but I've tried on Win 10 1803 (OS Build 17134.48) which is not a inside preview version even in that I'm facing same issue. Do I've to be specifically on 17134.1 to get this working ?

Comment: According MSDN blog configurable updates check is available on Build 17134 (April 2018 Update, Version 1804) but my windows 10 version was still 1803 so I'm working on inside preview version to get a build closer to version 1804.

Comment: @aneupane The latest update (17134.81) includes some specific fixes for the appinstaller story. If you could still reproduce the problem on this specific version, please feel free tell me.

Comment: @Xavier Xie -MSFT.  Yes, I tried this on 17134.81 and I had same issue. (Just a thought: If in case auto-update works perfectly on version 17134.81 then isn't it supposed to work perfectly on pre-release version 17677.100 as it is a later version even though it is in pre-release.)

Comment: I am having the exact same problem - on 17.134.285. I need to roll my LOB app out to many users soon and was relying on this new web update feature - is this a known problem?

Comment: Still having the problem on 17763.