# UWP app-installer auto update only updates once

Tags: uwp

I am generating my app through Visual Studio 2017 15.7.6, uploading it to Azure along with the appinstaller file etc. Lets say version 0.1.11.0
It is set to update every time the app opens

```
<UpdateSettings>
    <OnLaunch HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" />
</UpdateSettings>
```

I then install via the web on a Win 10 machine running 1803 (17134.285).

I then create a new apppackage with version 0.1.12.0.

I upload this to Azure and open the app on the target machine - it updates correctly. There are lots of logs under 
Microsoft/Windows/AppXDeployment-Server/Operational

> Deployment Register operation with target volume C: on Package MyApp_0.1.12.0_x86__8m1jne1se2ktw from:  (AppxBundleManifest.xml)  finished successfully.

I then create another apppackage 0.1.13.0 - upload it to Azure. I go back to the target machine but it will not update. There is nothing in the event log.

I move my system clock 24 hours.
In the event log it shows checks being run for other apps (Netflix) but not my app.

If I install the latest version (0.1.13.0) from the web and then again upload a new version 0.1.14.0 it again updates.
But it won't update the next version.

So it's only updating once.

Someone else describes what looks like a very similar problem from a few months ago:
[UWP app-installer auto update not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611910/uwp-app-installer-auto-update-not-working-correctly#)

**UPDATE**: I have now tested this with a basic app that simply displays the app version on the screen. I created 5 x app packages and uploaded them to the server.

Version 1.0.0.0 - installed from web

Version 1.0.1.0 - auto updated
(Changed appinstaller and index.html to point to new version each time)

Version 1.0.2.0 - would not auto update. I updated via server.

Version 1.0.3.0 - auto updated

Version 1.0.4.0 - would not auto update

I have tested this now on 2 x different machines both on 1803 (17134.285). This auto updating must be working for others out there??

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Microsoft have confirmed to me on the MSDN forums that this is a known issue. No time scale on a fix yet.